# Why does learning languages help with averting dementia?

Tags: neurology

I heard that several studies (e.g. [1](http://lcad.lab.yorku.ca/files/2015/03/view.pdf), [2](http://www.pphp.concordia.ca/fac/phillips/files/ChertkowetalbilingualismADAD2010.pdf)) point out that learning several languages help with averting dementia and Alzheimer's disease, especially when the languages are learned at a young age and when the languages are used often.

However, the studies that I can find only point at numerical evidence. I am wondering whether it is known what happens in the brain when learning and using multiple languages that delays dementia and Alzheimer's disease.

Comment: Great question and a fascinating topic, but I believe this crosses into *off topic* territory for ***this*** site. I think it's neat that learning a language might be found to help dementia patents, but the neuroscience of dementia is a subject of [cognitive sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com) or possibly [Health](http://health.stackexchange.com). This question doesn't really deal with expertise or learning techniques of language acquisition as intended by this site. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: If you ask the question like "how disease X affects learning language?", then I think it will be on-topic again